# How to check if a list ends with another list?

Tags: list

Currently I'm using a fairly inefficient way to check if one list uses another list at it's end. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```el
(defun is-in-list (ls-haystack ls-ends-with)
  (catch 'found
    (while (not (or (eq ls-haystack t) (null ls-haystack)))
      (when (eq ls-haystack ls-ends-with)
        (throw 'found t))
      (setq ls-haystack (cdr ls-haystack)))))
```

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is known in Common Lisp as
[`tailp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ldiffc.htm) and is present in
Emacs Lisp as
[`cl-tailp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Lists-as-Sets.html):

```
(defun cl-tailp (sublist list)
  "Return true if SUBLIST is a tail of LIST."
  (while (and (consp list) (not (eq sublist list)))
    (setq list (cdr list)))
  (if (numberp sublist) (equal sublist list) (eq sublist list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nthcdr`:

```el
(let* ((x '(4 5))
       (y `(1 2 3 . ,x)))
  (eq (nthcdr (- (length y) (length x)) y)
      x))
;; => t
```

```el
(defun foo (list list2)
  "Return t if LIST ends with LIST2."
  (eq (nthcdr (- (length list) (length list2)) list)
      list2))

(let ((x (list 4 5)))
  (foo (cons 1 (cons 2 x))
       x))
;; => t

;; it is ok if LIST is shorter than LIST2
(foo '(1 2) '(1 2 3 4))
;; => nil
```